# Create a series of json string from a nsmutablearray

Tags: ios, objective-c

Im using the following code to create  a json string from an array.

```
for (int k = 0 ; k < [[self totalCompliancesCount] count]; k++) {
        delayedJsonObject = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        [delayedJsonObject setValue:[[self totalCompliancesCount] objectAtIndex:k] forKey:@"t"];
        [delayedJsonObject setValue:[[self totalCompliedCompliancesCount] objectAtIndex:k] forKey:@"y"];
        delayedJsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:delayedJsonObject options:0 error:nil];
        delayedJsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[delayedJsonData bytes] length:[delayedJsonData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    }
```

`[[self totalCompliancesCount] count]` is 6. so the  delayedJsonString has to contain 6 jsonobjects within it but it contains only the last json object.
How can I sort this out?

Comment: You are creating new 'delayedJsonString' object on every iteration so at the end you only see the last iteration value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get your question correctly, you wanted to have a string based on a list of object.

Maybe you can try something like this:

```
NSMutableArray *delayedJsonObjectList = [NSMutableArray new];
for (int k = 0 ; k < [[self totalCompliancesCount] count]; k++) {
    delayedJsonObject = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [delayedJsonObject setValue:[[self totalCompliancesCount] objectAtIndex:k] forKey:@"t"];
    [delayedJsonObject setValue:[[self totalCompliedCompliancesCount] objectAtIndex:k] forKey:@"y"];   
    [delayedJsonObjectList addObject:delayedJsonObject];
}
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *delayedJsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:delayedJsonOjbectList options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:delayedJsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Just whipped this up just now didn't test it yet. will update after testing

## OUTPUT : (assumed data)

[{"t":1,"y":2},{"t":1,"y":2},{"t":1,"y":2},{"t":1,"y":2}..]

Answer (score 1):

You're effectively recreating the `delayedJsonString` every iteration of your loop rather than appending onto the end.

Try something like:

```
NSMutableString *delayedJsonString = @"".mutableCopy;
for (int k = 0 ; k < [[self totalCompliancesCount] count]; k++) {
    delayedJsonObject = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [delayedJsonObject setValue:[[self totalCompliancesCount] objectAtIndex:k] forKey:@"t"];
    [delayedJsonObject setValue:[[self totalCompliedCompliancesCount] objectAtIndex:k] forKey:@"y"];
    delayedJsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:delayedJsonObject options:0 error:nil];
    [delayedJsonString appendString:[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[delayedJsonData bytes] length:[delayedJsonData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];        
}
```

Comment: it works . The output is  `{"t":0,"y":0}{"t":0,"y":0}{"t":1,"y":1}{"t":0,"y":0}{"t":1,"y":1}{"t":2,"y":2}` but there is not comma in between each json object. How can I sort this out?

Answer (score 0):

You need to move this line outside of the loop:

```
delayedJsonObject = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
```